# Fibered product of commutative squares

Tags: category-theory

$\require{AMScd}\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}$

Consider the following two commutative diagrams where $X':=X\times_{\operatorname{Spec} k, f_k} \operatorname{Spec} k$ is the pullback of $X$ along $f_k$ the absolute frobenius of $\operatorname{Spec} k$

$$\begin{CD}
X' @>f>> X \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\operatorname{Spec}  k @>f_k>> \operatorname{Spec}k
\end{CD}$$

and

$$\begin{CD}
S @>f_S>> S \\
@VVV @VVV \\
S @>f_S>> S
\end{CD}$$

> Prove that this diagram is commutative

$$\begin{CD}
X'\times S @>(\pi_1,f_S)>> X\times S \\
@VVV @VVV \\
S @>f_S>> S
\end{CD}$$
where $f_S$ the absolute frobenius of $S$ and $\pi_1$ is the first projection.

---

I am trying to find a solution using [2-fibre products](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/003O) but I don't know where to start, can we see a commutative square as an object and construct the fibered product of two squares?

Thank you for any hep.

Comment: Is $k$ one of the fields $\mathbb{F}_q$ for $q = p^n$ and is $f_k$ the Frobenius on $k$, i.e., is $f_k(x) = x^{q}$ for $q = \lvert \mathbb{F}_q\rvert$?

Comment: @Geoff indeed $k$ is a field of characteristic $p>0$, and for me I thought of the frobenius as the identity on topological spaces and the $p$-power on rings, so $f_k(x)=x^p$ for $x\in k$ and  $f_S(x)=x^p$ for $x\in \mathcal O_S$ .Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Categorical Answer**

There's nothing complicated here.

Just check commutativity directly. The vertical maps are the projections onto the second factor. By definition of $(\pi_1,f_S)$ (which only makes sense if I assume you really mean $\pi_1\times f_S$), we have $\pi_2(\pi_1,f_S)=f_S\pi_2$, which is what you get when you go around the other way.

**The Algebraic Geometry Answer**

If you want an even more explicit calculation, we have the following:

Without loss of generality you may assume that $X$ and $S$ are affine, since pullbacks (and products) are computed locally.

Then if $S=\newcommand\Spec{\operatorname{Spec}}\Spec A$, $X=\Spec B$, for $A$, $B$ $k$-algebras, and if $\phi_k : k\to k$ and $\phi_A : A\to A$ are the Frobenius maps, we have that 
$X' = \Spec (B\otimes_{\phi} k)$, and we need to show that the following diagram commutes: 
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>\phi_A>> A\\
@Va\mapsto a \otimes 1 VV @VVa\mapsto a \otimes 1 \otimes 1V
\\
A\otimes_k B 
@>>a\otimes b \mapsto \phi_A(a) \otimes b\otimes 1>
A\otimes_k(B\otimes_\phi k)\\
\end{CD}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! Just one question about the categorical answer, do you consider that $\pi_2$ is the same map for both projections onto the second factor?

Comment: @PerelMan The two $\pi_2$s are different. They have different domains, so they can't be the same.

Comment: indeed, thank you very much for your help!